# Belgium internship visa from non-EU country

Tags: indian-citizens, belgium

I am an Indian citizen pursuing studies in France. Now I got a paid internship in Brussels which will last six months. Currently I am in India and I want to apply for a Belgian visa from India.

I understand that I will be needing a type D long-stay visa. But I couldn't find out what category visa I will need.

I see there's a specific Internship visa category in the website of the [Belgian consulate in France](https://france.diplomatie.belgium.be/sites/default/files/content/download/consulair/Paris/Frans/Visa/stage_art._9_13.pdf) but I couldn't find a similar category in the website of the [Belgian consulate in India](https://india.diplomatie.belgium.be/en/travel-to-belgium/visa/india).

I mailed the consulate here in India and they informed that I will be needing "visa D - Single Permit". But the employer has only provided "BIS goedkeuren opleidingsplan". I guess this is not a work permit? Or is this document sufficient to get a "single permit" visa?